# MongoDB $facet aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm having a problem in my $facet aggregation. I want to know also if it is **byAllProduct** I will know that this product is the **bestSeller**, **newlyAdded**, and **mostReviewed**.

```
$facet: {
    "byBestSeller": [  
        { $sort: { "sold":-1 }},  
        { $limit: 1 }    
    ],
    "byMostReviewed": [  
        { $addFields: { "noOfReviews": {$size:"$reviews.message"}}},
        { $sort: { "noOfReviews":-1 }},
        { $limit: 1 }    
    ],
    "byNewlyAdded": [  
        { $sort: { "createdAt":-1 }},  
        { $limit: 1 }
    ],
    "byAllProducts": [  
        { $limit:  100 }
    ],
}
```

Now, my result is this.

```
    "byBestSeller": [
      {
        "sold": 150,
        "name": "Big Mac",
        "shop": [
          {
            "name": "McDonald's"
          }
        ],
        "createdAt": {
          "2020-05-11T01:55:17.623Z"
        },
        "reviews": [
          {
            "message": "Yummylicious"
          },
          {
            "message": "Yummy burger"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
"byMostReviewed": [
      {
        "sold": 100,
        "name": "Spaghetti",
        "shop": [
          {
            "name": "McDonald's"
          }
        ],
        "createdAt": {
          "2020-06-11T01:55:17.623Z"
        },
        "reviews": [
          {
            "message": "Yummylicious"
          },
          {
            "message": "Yummy Spaghetti"
          },
          {
            "message": "Yummy super rich spag."
          }
        ],
            "noOfReviews": 3
      }
    ],
"byNewlyArrived": [
      {
        "sold": 0,
        "name": "Fries",
        "shop": [
          {
            "name": "McDonald's"
          }
        ],
        "createdAt": {
          "2020-7-11T01:55:17.623Z"
        },
        "reviews": [
          {
            "message": "Yummylicious"
          },
        ]
      }
    ],
"byAllProducts": [
    {
        "sold": 150,
        "name": "Big Mac",
        "shop": [
          {
            "name": "McDonald's"
          }
        ],
        "createdAt": {
          "2020-05-11T01:55:17.623Z"
        },
        "reviews": [
          {
            "message": "Yummylicious"
          },
          {
            "message": "Yummy burger"
          }
        ]
      }
      {
        "sold": 100,
        "name": "Fries",
        "shop": [
          {
            "name": "McDonald's"
          }
        ],
        "createdAt": {
          "2020-06-11T01:55:17.623Z"
        },
        "reviews": [
          {
            "message": "Yummylicious"
          },
          {
            "message": "Yummy Spaghetti"
          },
          {
            "message": "Yummy super rich spag."
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "sold": 0,
        "name": "Fries",
        "shop": [
          {
            "name": "McDonald's"
          }
        ],
        "createdAt": {
          "2020-07-11T01:55:17.623Z"
        },
        "reviews": [
          {
            "message": "Yummylicious"
          },
        ]
      }
    ],
```

Is there a way so that even if it is included in all products I can know that it is the *bestSeller*, *mostReviewed*, and *newlyarrived*?